# Nginx - URL rewrite rules

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, nginx

I have for example this URL:

> www.example.com/folder1/folder2/edit.php?username=nickname

Actually I have this rewrite rules:

```
location / {
    root   /var/www;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;

    # First rewrite rule output: www.example.com/nickname

    rewrite ^/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)$ /folder1/folder2/user.php?username=$1;

    # Second rewrite rule output: www.example.com/nickname/edit

    rewrite ^/([A-Za-z]+)/edit$ /folder1/folder2/edit.php?username=$1;
}
```

However, that works fine.

But I need to rewrite my URL like this:

> www.example.com/nickname/edit/info

It has a couple of parameters:

> www.example.com/folder1/folder2/edit.php?username=nickname&info=basic

I tried everything but with no success:

```
location / {
    root   /var/www;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;

    # First rewrite rule output: www.example.com/nickname
    rewrite ^/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)$ /folder1/folder2/user.php?username=$1;

    # Second rewrite rule output: www.example.com/nickname/edit
    rewrite ^/([A-Za-z]+)/edit$ /folder1/folder2/edit.php?username=$1;

    # Here where I'm stuck
    # www.example.com/nickname/edit/info

    rewrite ^/edit/([A-Za-z]+)/info$ /folder1/folder2/edit.php?user=$1&info=$2;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last attempt seems to have mixed up the location of `edit`. Also, nothing is passed to `info` as there is only one capturing group, perhaps

`rewrite ^/([A-Za-z]+)/edit/([A-Za-z]+)$ /folder1/folder2/edit.php?username=$1&info=$2;`

will work instead?